# Rewrite url & redirect to mobile page in one htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite my sites' URL's so that you don't have to put the '.html' at the end, and I also want to redirect to a mobile page when you are a phone user, in my .htaccess file.

Right now I can't get both codes (I copied) to work together; My desktop site seems to work fine with the rewriting, but on the mobile page, I get the 'too many redirects' error. I am very new to the rewriting and redirecting so perhaps the answer is quite simple...

below is my .htaccess code:

````
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
  RewriteRule ^ http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.html\ HTTP
  RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301]

  RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
  RewriteRule (.*) $1\.html [L]
</IfModule>

# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
    RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

    # Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
    RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

    # cookie can't be set and read in the same request so check
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
    RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

    # Check if this looks like a mobile device
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

    # Check if we're not already on the mobile site
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
    # Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
    # Now redirect to the mobile site
    RewriteRule ^ http://m.danielsante.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L] ```
````